# possessive pronoun in complex sentence

Tags: pronouns, possessives, subjects

I have a question regarding this sentence:

> The personalities of project leaders affect *their* reactions while they face problems in the project.

Do you think that the sentence is grammatically correct and clear?

I'm afraid people will be confused that the word *their* refers to *the personalities of project leaders* instead of to *the project leaders*.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is with _while_ (indicates a time interval whilst 'reactions' are punctive, and this doesn't work well here); the antecedent of _their_ is easily retrievable.

Comment: There's no confusion because personalities don't have reactions or face problems, people do.

Answer (score -1):

Know that "their" is the possessive form of the pronoun "them", which is used to refer to the object of the clause. The basic sentence structure is **subject + does something to + object**. In your sentence, the **personalities of the project leaders** + **is affecting** + **them (the project leaders)**. "Project leaders" is the object, thus "their" refers to *them*.

**TD;DR**: You have structured the sentence correctly as "project leaders" is the only phrase that can be referred to "them".

Sources: [Them and They](http://www.onestopenglish.com/methodology/teaching-tips/ask-the-experts/grammar-questions/grammar-them-and-they/146352.article), [Object Clauses](http://www.icaltefl.com/object-clauses%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E-in-english-grammar)

Comment: I'm not sure of your reasoning here. Do you think that a possessive pronoun may only refer to an object? Or that it may only refer to persons? BTW, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @deadrat The possessive pronoun refers to persons.

Comment: Not always. I refer you to Sigmund Freud's *Civilization and **its** Discontents*.

Comment: I think it generally depends on what's being possessed. A personality can't possess a reaction, so the antecedent must be the people. But if it said "their expressions", it could refer to the personalities, since personalities can have expressions.